# Solving a PDE $\frac{\partial H(x,t)}{\partial t} = H(x,t) + f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have an equation of the general form:

$$ \frac{\partial H(x,t)}{\partial t} = H(x,t) + f(x)  $$

The actual $f(x)$ is a bit complex but is purely a function of x.  I'd like to get a general solution for $H(x,t)$ and I'm not quite sure where to start.

First, since the derivative is strictly in t, can I assume that f(x) is a constant and solve as an ODE through separation of variables?  If so, I think I can work with that.  My concern here is whether the constant of integration would be the same for all x.

Second, if I cannot for whatever reason treat this as on ODE, where could I start?  I've tried using NDSolve (and DSolve) in Mathematica with no results (but lots of error messages!).  I don't need a general solution; numeric would suffice.  If it helps, there is a boundary condition of $H(x,0) = 0$.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Assuming I can indeed treat this as an ODE, does this work?

$$\frac{\partial H(x,t)}{\partial t} = - c H(x,t) + A(x)$$

Convert to ODE:

$$\frac{d H(t)}{d t} = - c H(t) + A$$

Separate variables:

$$\frac{\frac{d H(t)}{dt}}{A - c (H(t)} = 1$$

Integrate and solve for H:

$$\int \frac{\frac{d H(t)}{dt}}{A - c (H(t)} dt = \int dt$$

$$- \frac{\ln (A - c H(t))}{c} = t + k$$

$$H(t) = \frac{A - e^{-c(t+k)}}{c}$$

Solve for k assuming $H(0) = 0$:

$$k = - \frac{ln (A)}{c}$$

Plug in and simplify:

$$H(t) = \frac{A - e^{\ln (A)- \frac{c}{t}}}{c}$$

$$H(t) = \frac{A(1-e^{-\frac{c}{t}})}{c}$$

Reintroduce x:

$$H(x,t) = \frac{A(x)(1-e^{-\frac{c}{t}})}{c}$$

Comment: Notice the PDE $\;\partial_t H(x,t) = -cH(x,t) + f(x)\;$ can be rewritten as
$$e^{-ct}\partial_t (e^{ct}H(x,t)) = f(x)
\quad\iff\quad\partial_t( e^{ct}H(x,t)) = f(x)e^{ct}$$

If one integrate on both sides, one get
$$e^{ct}H(x,t) - H(x,0) = \int_0^t \partial_s (e^{cs}H(x,s)) ds = \int_0^t f(x) e^{cs} ds$$
This implies
$$H(x,t) = e^{-ct}\left( H(x,0) + f(x) \int_0^t e^{cs} ds\right)
= H(x,0) e^{-ct} + \frac1c f(x)(1 - e^{-ct})
$$

Comment: I would try to ask the question in mathematica SE if you are seeking for a numerical solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something missing at the point below :

[image]

$K(x)\:$ is an arbitrary function. One can include the constant $\:k\:$ into $\:K(x)\:$

Then, you can include $\:K(x)\:$ in the equations up to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that
\begin{equation*}
H(x,t)=H(x,0)e^{t}+(e^{t}-1)f(x)
\end{equation*}
as can be checked by differentiation.